# ASP.NET MVC Hierarchy Url Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-routing

I have a problem

My route have an extra paramater after hierarchical category.

> /2009/World/Asia/08/12/bla-bla-bla

asp.net mvc does not support this because my routing should be

> {year}/{*category}/{month}/{day}/{name}

i tried use constraint like

```
year = @"(\d{4})",category = @"((.+)/)+", month = @"(\d{2})", day = @"(\d{2})"
```

but i cannot find any solution.

Is there any comment?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the route handler tokenizes on the slash character so you won't be able to have a category that includes a slash -- though escaping it might work, not sure about that.  You might want to format your URL as:

```
/2009/World+Asia/08/12/bla-bla-bla
```

This should translate the category as "World Asia".

If that doesn't work then perhaps you need another route that matches on subcategory as well.

```
{year}/{category}/{subcategory}/{month}/{day}/{name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another rule to your routing with the name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to limit and put some constraints on values can pass as routing sections, You can do it with Route Constraint. Plaese read [Creating a Route Constraint (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) and you will find how that is possible. You can do it same as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
 );
```

The regular expression **\d+** matches one or more integers. This constraint causes the Product route to match the following URLs:

> /Product/3
>
> /Product/8999

But not the following URLs:

> /Product/apple
>
> /Product

**Additionally** you could write your custom route constraint, Please read [Creating a Custom Route Constraint (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) and see below sample I just copied from [This post by Guy Burstein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bursteg/2009/01/11/aspnet-mvc-route-constraints/) that I think you find it useful:

```
public class FromValuesListConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
      public FromValuesListConstraint(params string[] values)
      {
        this._values = values;
      }

      private string[] _values;

      public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, 
        Route route, 
        string parameterName, 
        RouteValueDictionary values, 
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
      {
        // Get the value called "parameterName" from the 
        // RouteValueDictionary called "value"
        string value = values[parameterName].ToString();

        // Return true is the list of allowed values contains 
        // this value.
        return _values.Contains(value);
      }
    }
```

As Guy said: **In order to implement a Custom Route Constraint, you should create a class that inherits from IRouteConstraint, and implement the Match method.**

Hope this help.